# How can I merge two arrays declared as void pointers?

Tags: void-pointers

I currently have I program I am writing where I am implementing a Mergesort of an array.  The array is of unknown variables--it is a void pointer, so I don't actually know what sort of objects I'm sorting (there is a comparison function passed in for the actual comparisons).

How can I traverse the array when it is a void pointer?  I've learned that I can't just use typical array format (i.e. `arr[3]`) since it is a void pointer.  There IS a parameter passed into my functions that holds the size of the mystery elements, so I suppose I would need that.  Is there a way I could cast it depending on the provided size so I COULD use that typical array format, or do I have to use pointer arithmetic (again, having to somehow cast it to something of the provided size)?

Thanks to anyone who provides some input! :)

Comment: Why did you delete your code >.>

Answer (score 2):

> There IS a parameter passed into my functions that holds the size of the mystery elements

Good - that is precisely what you need to do the pointer arithmetic right. This is the same approach that [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) library function is using.

```
void merge_sort(void *array, size_t N, size_t size, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *));
```

Once you cast the `void*` pointer to a `char*`, you would be able to compute the location of the mystery element `i` as follows:

```
size_t size; // Element size
void *array; // The address of the array
size_t N;    // Count of elements in the array
char *base = array;
for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++) {
    void *elementAtPositionI = &base[i * size];
    ...
}
```

To find the point at which you split the array for sorting separately you can use the same technique:

```
void *secondHalf = &base[N * size / 2];
```

> I can't quite get it to work though... it seems as if I'm skipping values and going into memory past the array!

A couple of major issues remain in your code:

- Your code skips values because you calculate the sizes of the left and the right parts incorrectly: you assume that they both are `num_elem/2`, when in fact one of them is `num_elem/2+1` when `num_elem` is odd. Use `num_elem/2` for the left side and `num_elem-num_elem/2` for the right side. Find all places where your assumption is made, and fix them (there's more than one place).
- Your code goes into wrong memory because you calculate the position of the middle incorrectly. You need to make a fix on this line: `merge(carr, carr + (num_elem/2) /* <<== HERE */, num_elem/2, num_elem/2, elem_size, cmp);`
- You are copying elements into `helper` incorrectly. Instead of `helper[helper_place * elem_size] = *a_temp;` you need to call `memcpy` and use `elem_size` for the number of bytes to copy. There are several spots where you need to make this fix.

This should bring you a lot closer to a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I rewrote all my code to use char pointers.  I can't quite get it to work though... it seems as if I'm skipping values and going into memory past the array!

Comment: That was exactly it!  Thank you so much.  Void pointers tend to be my weakness XD  Luckily I don't have to deal with them much beyond this, at least in this specific program :)

Answer (score 1):

In `mergesort`, you need to treat the pointers as `char*`, You will need to pass the size of the objects so you would know how to perform pointer arithmetic correctly.

```
void mergesort(void* a, void* b, size_t objectSize, size_t objectCount)
{
   char* ac = (char*)a;
   char* bc = (char*)b;

   //.....

   mergesort(ac, ac+objectSize*objectCount/2);
}
```

Comment: This makes sense--I didn't even think I'd have to adjust my entire sorting algorithm, but it would make sense that I would have to.